# Control Firebase Storage rules from the application level

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have an application in Firestore that stores user files in the cloud. And here's my question, is it possible for me to set rules through the application? At this point I have something like that:

```
rules_version = '2';

function isAdmin() {
   return request.auth !=null && request.auth.uid in [
        "Xk60AqYDM4ONw5VOR0v89c8RF9P2",
        "3e8kXyjUvUY8WOHp75Z1Y278OO63"
    ];
}

function companyJP(){
       return request.auth !=null && request.auth.uid in [
        "CUTSs8oziESYDzPqyv2ac7XOKMD2",
        "gqTFDiP7lYeaCaYFd9SG52LCMYF3"
    ];
}

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{userID}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
    }
    match /files/{groupId}/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read: if resource.metadata.owner == request.auth.token.groupId;
        allow write: if request.auth.token.groupId == groupId;
        }
    match /files/adminFiles/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAdmin(); 
    }
    match /files/companyJP/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if firmaJP(); 
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to set these rules via a web application. Are there any commands for this? Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "set rules through the application"? Dynamically changing the values of the userIds (i.e. Xk60AqYDM4ONw5VOR0v89c8RF9P2)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, precisely managing users and their rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the code of the Security Rules from your front-end application.

What you could do in **Firestore** Security Rules is to base some conditional statements of the rules (e.g. `allow read`) on either the existence of some Firestore document or on values contained in document fields. For that you would use the `get()` and `exists()` functions, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in the doc. So, from your front-end, you could modify the values of those Firestore documents, to dynamically modify the result of the Security Rules statements.

**HOWEVER**, in your case you are writing rules for **Cloud Storage**, and it is not possible, in Cloud Storage Security Rules, to access data or documents stored into Firestore.

---

One solution is to use [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). You will be able, through Custom Claims, to implement a role-based access control. Concretely, you can assign the `companyJP` attribute to the account of user `CUTSs8oziESYDzPqyv2ac7XOKMD2` (Please read the doc for more precise details).

And you can, from your front-end application, allow some specific (admin) users to change the claims (i.e. the roles) of other users. Since Custom Claims can only be set from a privileged server environment by the Firebase Admin SDK, the easiest way is to use a Callable Cloud Function that you call from your front-end (and in which you check that the user who is calling the Cloud Function has the Admin privilege).

You will probably be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which explains how to build a module which allows Firebase end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users and assigning them other specific user roles.

Comment: Will there be any charges for a small application? This is about features in Firebase.

Comment: Do you mean any cost? **The use of Custom Claims** (and of the other Authentication services, apart phone auth, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)) **does not incur any cost**. Actually, what would incur some cost is the solution based on Firestore documents I mentioned at the beginning of my answer: since this solution is based on Firestore documents, you would pay the cost of documents reading.